# How to set X rotation of object the same as X rotation of VR controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I've got a object which has the x rotation same as controller of vr.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(controller.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0);
```

But I need to rotate it 90 degrees that the object will be **vertically** not horizontally.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(controller.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + 90, 0, 0);
```

But this doesn't work properly, because you can rotate the object in only one direction.

If you rotate controller **right** -> object rotate **right** & if you rotate controller **left** -> object rotate **right**.
If you want to rotate object left you have to rotate controller upside down.

I also tried set the object as child of controller but on play the object **disappear**.

How can I solve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign your rotation to be equal to the controller's right vector.

```
this.transform.rotation =  Quaternion.LookRotation(controller.transform.right, Vector3.up);
```